# Execution plan for implementing the [local-autonomy] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Execution plan for implementing [local-autonomy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/local-autonomy). *See*, [If the goal of [secession] is to gain [independence], is it necessary to have both tags?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5955/26455)

To allow time for objections to be made, I will make no changes until September 6, 2021.

After the changes, [local-autonomy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/local-autonomy) will have 6 questions.

Other questions, currently tagged [independence](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independence), will either be dropped (7) or changed to [secession](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secession) (57). Some questions tagged [secession](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secession) will either be re-tagged as [local-autonomy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/local-autonomy) or have the tag added.

In the course of my review, I found

- some questions have tags that are not related to the question, only mere reference in the question, those are marked "incidental reference" and should be removed;
- several questions that could use other tags, those are noted, below;
- (Unrelated to the implementation, a tag for Somaliland will be added with 3 questions getting the tag.)

---

1. Remove [independence](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independence) tags (Clean-up)

a. Duplicates: [independence](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independence) and [secession](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secession)

- <strike>[Would the rest of the UK lose anything more than honor if Scotland exits the UK?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/59529/26455)</strike>
- [Do any countries have a procedure that allows a constituent part of that country to become independent unilaterally?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/48316/26455)
- [Can Catalonia enter the EU after its independence from Spain?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/19870/26455)

b. Unrelated to tag usage

- <strike>[Having problem in grasping a feature of Directive Principle of State Policy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/53066/26455)</strike>
- Incidental reference [Why would Madrid be so insistent on preventing the Catalonian independence referendum?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/25010/26455)
- Incidental reference [palestine](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palestine) [When is a country recognized as a sovereign state?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/9981/26455)

---

2. Change excerpt for [secession](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secession)

> Questions about the withdrawal of a group from a larger entity, especially a political entity. Use with a country or other tag to identify the entity. For question about "local independence" use [local-autonomy], instead.

---

3. Establish the [local-autonomy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/local-autonomy) tag.

- <strike>Remove [secession](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secession) incidental reference [scotland](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scotland) add [local-autonomy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/local-autonomy) [Is there are non-independent country with “full fiscal autonomy”?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/8287/26455)</strike>
- Add excerpt

> Questions about actions or movements that promote a greater degree of self-government within a country or political subdivision, or whether an area is independent. Use with a country tag. When the question is about full independence from a country, use the [secession] tag, instead.

---

4. Posts selected for the new [local-autonomy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/local-autonomy) tag, replacing [independence](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independence).

- <strike>[How does the Barnett Formula work?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/50453/26455)</strike>
- [If India got independence in 1947, how come there were governments by Indians before then?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/47921/26455)
- [Pakistan Occupied Kashmir](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/43651/26455)

---

5. Add tags (Additional tags discovered during review)

- <strike>[debt](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debt) [Which country is responsible for the external debt if half of the states of a country become independent? [duplicate]](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/60868/26455)</strike>
- [local-autonomy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/local-autonomy) [What other European countries are experiencing independence movements?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/25683/26455)
- [local-autonomy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/local-autonomy) [Secessionist / Regionalist political parties in Germany](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/41381/26455)
- [sovereignty](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sovereignty) [Independence referendum Vs Country sovereignty](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/25032/26455)
- [european-union](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/european-union) [Is it difficult for Scotland to become a member of the EU if they gain independence from the UK following Brexit](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/16451/26455)
- [referendum](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/referendum) [Could Westminster block the possibility of a referendum on Scottish independence?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/11352/26455)
- [somalia](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/somalia) [somaliland](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/somaliland) [Why does the international community recognise South Sudan independence, but not Somaliland?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/10312/26455)
- [alaska](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alaska) [Could Alaska leave the US, or would it have to buy its way out?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/10536/26455)
- [political-spectrum](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-spectrum) [Why are some secessionist movements on the left but others on the right?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/8463/26455)

---

6. Retag (Other tag changes discovered during review)

- <strike>remove [independence](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independence) add [voting](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voting) [Why bother stopping people from voting? [duplicate]](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/25025/26455)</strike>
- remove [sovereignty](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sovereignty) add [tibet](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tibet) [How did various countries come to the position that Tibet is a part of China? Roughly which and how many countries do not have a position?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/12384/26455)
- remove [nationalism](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nationalism) [sovereignty](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sovereignty) add [public-opinion](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-opinion) [How supported is the idea of a fully independent Indian state among US Native Americans?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/1813/26455). Question is requesting results of [public-opinion] surveys about the desire for the [secession] of the occupied lands of the [indigenous-people] of the [united-states].
- remove [federalism](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/federalism) [anarchism](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anarchism) add [local-autonomy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/local-autonomy) [Does the increased localization of government control provide a solution to the stalemate caused by two party politics?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/30208/26455)

---

7. Create synonyms

- For [local-autonomy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/local-autonomy), [devolution](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devolution)
- For [secession](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secession), [independence-movement](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independence-movement)
- Make [independence](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independence) a synonym of [secession](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secession)

---

8. Additional changes for an added tag.

- Add excerpt for [somaliland](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/somaliland)

> Questions about the Republic of Somaliland, an unrecognised sovereign state internationally considered to be part of Somalia.

Add tags

- <strike>[somaliland](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/somaliland) [Why is Somaliland not recognized by any country?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/18970/26455)</strike>
- [somaliland](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/somaliland) [Why does the African Union defer to Somalia on the question of Somaliland's suzerainty?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/64064/26455)

Comment: Typical of "incidental reference" is that an example is given regarding some country. This is followed by a question regarding the example. If changing the example to a different country would change a country tag, the country and its tag are "incidental" to the question.

Comment: Which time zone are you using to determine September 6th?

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica - The first change should be made about 2021-09-06T20:00Z, if things are not very busy. After that, changes will be made 2 - 3 per day to keep from seemingly monopolizing the "Top Questions". About 10 - 15 days total depending on other questions.